# Necesito recorrer una columna e ir obteniendo los valores de cada celda

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un problema con GAS en una hoja de calculo.
Necesito recorrer una columna e ir obteniendo los valores de cada celda, por separado, pero hasta ahora solo conseguí recuperar el valor completo de cada fila.

Dejo el código que vengo creando

```
function myFunction() {
   var sps = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  var sheet = sps.getSheets();
  var data = sheet[0].getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=2;i<10;i++){
   var fila = data[i,4]; 

  Logger.log(fila);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de

```
var fila = data[i,4];
```

usa

```
var fila = data[i][4];
```