# Buscando indice con array.indexof en GAS

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, array-bidimensional

Tengo dos hojas en el mismo archivo de spreadsheet de google. En una hoja tengo una columna con el listado de unos 2000 ids, que están relacionados con la siguiente columna llamada razón.

En otra hoja, tengo unas 1000 empresas en una columna.
El caso es que en la hoja 1 las "razones" son nombres de empresa, y en esta hoja si que tengo los ids de cada empresa, pero en la hoja 2, no tengo los valores de la empresa. Los nombres son iguales en casi todos los casos, y necesito que en la hoja 2 también estén los ids de cada empresa.

He hecho tres arrays, en la hoja "hojaid", dos arrays, uno con los valores de razon y otro con los valores de ID y en la hoja "ppublico" un array con los valores de empresa:

```
var razon_values = hojaid.getRange(1,5,hojaid.getLastRow()-3).getValues();
var idcopia_values = hojaid.getRange(1,1,hojaid.getLastRow()-3).getValues();
var empresa_values =ppublico.getRange(1,25,ppublico.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

La intención es comparar a través de un bucle foreach los valores en los dos arrays de empresa y razon, y cuando coincida recuperar el indice en el que coincide en el array de razon, y usando ese indice recuperar el valor del id y pegarlo en la hoja de ppublico.

He hecho el siguiente script:

```
      for each (var empresa in empresa_values){
    var posicion_razon = razon_values.indexOf(empresa);
    ppublico.getRange(3,3).setValue(empresa);
    var idcopia = idcopia_values[posicion_razon];
         if (posicion_razon != -1){
         var posicion_empresa = empresa_values.indexOf(empresa);
         ppublico.getRange(posicion_empresa+1,1).setValue(idcopia);
         }
  o++
  ppublico.getRange(3,4).setValue(o); 
     }
```

}

Siempre me devuelve -1 en el registro la variable posicion_razon, no entiendo porque, ya que hay muchos nombres de empresa que coinciden.
He hecho un monton de pruebas, con valores iguales introducidos a mano en las casillas para luego compararlos, como por ejemplo esto:

```
    var razonval = razon_values[2];
Logger.log(razonval);
var empresaval = empresa_values[3];
Logger.log(empresaval);
if(razonval == empresaval){
Logger.log(razon_values[0];
}
```

sabiendo que razonval y empresaval tienen el mismo valor "a", pero aun asi el if cuando me lo compara no los identifica como iguales.

Ya no se que mas probar.
No se que estoy haciendo o entendiendo mal.
Una ayuda me vendría muy bien.

Comment: Bienvenido. Es bueno que hayas incluido código pero lo que esperamos es un [mcve]

Comment: Cabe destacar que `for each` ha sido deprecado por lo que no se recomienda su uso. Referencia https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for_each...in

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben, y perdón por lo del ejemplo mínimo verificable soy nuevo en este foro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que `getValues()` devuelve un objeto tipo Array que incluye objetos tipo Array donde cada uno de estos representa una fila y la posición de cada miembro representa una columna.

A los Arrays como los que devuelve `getValues()` también se les llama Array 2D, Array Multidimensional o matriz.

En `for each (var empresa in empresa_values)` la variable `empresa` será un Array, es por ello que `indexOf` siempre te devuelve `-1`.

En lugar de `for each` podrías usar

```
/** Columna que incluye los valores de empresa */
var columna = 0;
empresa_values.forEach(function(fila){ 
  var empresa = fila[columna];
  // Poner aquí lo que se va a hacer con la variable empresa
```

Cabe destacar que for each ha sido deprecado por lo que no se recomienda su uso. Referencia  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for_each...in

Relacionado

- [Necesito recorrer una columna e ir obteniendo los valores de cada celda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/253106/65)
- [Script recorrido de filas y columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/260105/65)
- [Búsqueda y comparación de datos en arrays](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/300364/65)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas, me sirven para investigar un poco mas, sobre todo para buscar el significado de "deprecado", que es algo que no acabo de entender, aunque según he podido leer debe de  ser como revocado o dejado en desuso.

Al final al día siguiente de publicar la pregunta di con la solución (no sin alguna hora de insomnio), y es convirtiendo en cada llamada foreach la variable recibida, la convierto a "string", para hacer la comparación y de esta manera, ya me hace la comparación de la manera deseada.

Aunque foreach haya sido deprecada como dice el articulo que comentáis, lo cierto es que a mi me ha funcionado al final de una manera muy optima, haciéndome toda la consulta en apenas 30 segundos. Antes de llegar a este método, lo primero que hice fue hacerlo con dos bucles for enlazados, y tardo media hora en compararme los datos del primer array de unos 1000 datos, con el otro array de 2000. Y con el bucle foreach, ¡¡¡apenas tardo en hacer los 1000 en 30 segundos!!!

Comment: Seguramente ya te estas dando cuenta que este sitio no es como otros. Aquí las respuestas deben responder la pregunta, no deben incluir gracias, saludos, firmas, lemas, anécdotas salvo que ayude a dar claridad a la respuesta, así como tampoco de explicaciones de porque se puso algo en la pregunta, si estas explicaciones son relevantes para hacer más clara la pregunta, por favor edita la pregunta para incluirlas en ella. Los saludos y comentarios al margen pueden incluirse en comentarios, con la salvedad de que estos pueden ser eliminados.

Comment: Cabe destacar que una vez que alcances 20 puntos de rep. podrás participar en el [chat].